# Does PHP have a Set data structure?

Tags: php, set

I'm new to PHP, and I can't figure out this basic question. Does PHP have some sort of set or list object? Something like an array, but with the ability to dynamically add or remove any number of objects from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you could use the [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) object and the [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Basically, you could dynamically grow an array using the [array_push](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function, or the `$arrayName[] = ...` notation (where arrayName is the name of your array).

Comment: A PHP array provides both a `List` and a `HashMap`, but not a `Set`. You can emulate a `Set` through the `HashMap` interface by setting your elements as an array key.

Comment: But then you can have sets only of scalar types. If I am correct, this is a poor solution.

Comment: This is outdated and does not create a `Set`, just a regular array. The question's title is misleading. The OP wasn't looking for a `Set` but ways to add elements to an array. If you are looking for a `Set`, look @okdewit answer below, using `Ds` lib. It uses a named keyed array in the background and adds a few helper methods (I would say there is no performance improvement against using a named key array directly).

Answer (score 14):

The PHP7+ answer: Use the official PHP-DS extension. It's much more efficient than hacky solutions using arrays. Sets come with some limitations, but most of the typical operations on them are much faster and provide a better interface.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ds.php

```php
<?php

use Ds\Set;

$numbers = new Set([1, 2, 3]);

$numbers->sum(); 

$numbers->diff(new Set([2, 3, 4]))
    ->union(new Set([3, 4, 5]))
    ->remove(...[3, 4])
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you've mentioned a "[Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28computer_science%29) object" in the question's title (i.e. if you need the objects not to be repeated within the set) , take a look at [SplObjectStorage](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) (php 5.3+).

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a `Set` data structure without repeated elements, it seems that as of PHP 7 the SPL adds support for a [Set](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ds-set.php) data structure.

Comment: Small clarification: it's not a part of `SPL`, it's `DS`. `SPL` is part PHP core, and it's always bundled, but `DS` is not, unfortunatetly (actual membership of the extension isn't clear, I couldn't find it in the [list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/extensions.membership.php))

Answer (score 3):

PHP's arrays like a mashup of ordered arrays indexed by a number, and a hash lookup table.  You can look up any element by a string index, but elements also have a defined order.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Set](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#set) from [Nspl](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl). It supports basic set operations which take other sets, arrays and traversable objects as arguments:

```
$set = set(1, 2);

$set->add('hello');
$set[] = 'world';

$set->delete('hello');

$array = [1, 2, 3];
$intersection = $set->intersection($array);

$anotherSet = Set::fromArray([1, 2, 3]);
$difference = $set->difference($anotherSet);

$iterator = new \ArrayIterator([1, 2, 3]);
$union = $set->union($iterator);

$isSubset = $set->isSubset([1, 2, 'hello', 'world']);

$isSuperset = $set->isSuperset([1, 2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a php array, there's no such thing as a 'fixed size' array in PHP so you should be fine with them.

Comment: Yes there is a fixed size array. It's called `SplFixedArray`. Please have a look over here: http://php.net/manual/en/splfixedarray.construct.php