# Array check if object key has same value

Tags: arrays, laravel, sorting

I want to push values from old array to a new array. when pushing I am checking the object value is already exist or not. the value should be pushed only when the same object value is not exist in new array. here is my code.

```
$sorted_array = array();

foreach ($data as $nkey => $value) {
        if (count($sorted_array) > 0) {
            dd($sorted_array[$nkey]);
            if ($sorted_array[$nkey]['store'] != $value['store']) {
                array_push($sorted_array, $value);
            }
        }
        else{
            array_push($sorted_array, $value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So essentially you want a [*set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type))? See e.g. [Does PHP have a Set data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764800/does-php-have-a-set-data-structure) (and look beyond the accepted answer)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you can easily handle it using the `in_array` function:

```
$sorted_array = array();

foreach ($data as $nkey => $value) {
        if ( !in_array($value, $sorted_array) ) {
            array_push($sorted_array, $value);
        }
}
```

`in_array` function return boolean value. In my code, if the `$value` parameter is not in the `$sorted_array`, then it will pushed. Otherwise operation is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

`array_push` in this case is wrong.
Try this code:

```
foreach ($data as $nkey => $value) {
    if (count($sorted_array) > 0) {
        if ($sorted_array[$nkey]['store'] != $value['store']) {
            $sorted_array[$nkey] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope can help you